# Right criteria doesn't meet in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, null

I would like to update my presale__c field if it's empty and quote status changed to Rejected, Active ans set it as sale__c field. I would like to do this without code. I am trying to use the flow.  I made this flow :
[image]

And put these conditions in the start block :
[image]

After this I put this record update block:
[image]

But when i debug this flow, i get Failure with this error :
[image]

I find it very strange. Any ideas in here why `presale(null) = null` criteria doesn't meet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Is Null` operator in condition 5 with comparand `$GlobalConstamt.True`

[image]

What you are doing is comparing against the string `null`